# Audio On Click Wave Sine

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

To add an audio player button to my website - I used the below which is to play and pause the audio when the icon is clicked.

I have managed to get the wave sine icon to "animate" as well as attached a function for 'play' and 'pause' to the wave icon to play and pause the audio.

However, What I need now is for the wave icon to "*stop animating / moving"* when the 'pause' function is triggered and the audio pauses.

```js
var audio = new Audio("https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3");

$('#play-pause-button').on("click",function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('fa-play'))
   {
     $(this).removeClass('fa-play');
     $(this).addClass('fa-pause');
     audio.play();
   }
  else
   {
     $(this).removeClass('fa-pause');
     $(this).addClass('fa-play');
     audio.pause();
   }
});

audio.onended = function() {
     $("#wave").removeClass('fa-pause');
     $("#wave").addClass('fa-play');
};



const path = document.querySelector('#wave');
const animation = document.querySelector('#moveTheWave');
const m = 0.512286623256592433;

function buildWave(w, h) {

  const a = h / 4;
  const y = h / 2;

  const pathData = [
  'M', w * 0, y + a / 2,
  'c',
  a * m, 0,
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,

  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a].
  join(' ');

  path.setAttribute('d', pathData);
}

buildWave(90, 60);
```

```css
#play-pause-button{
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  height: 110px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 110px;
}

body {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

svg {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wave {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 16 101 16;
  -webkit-animation: infinite;
          animation: moveTheWave 2400ms linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveTheWave {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -133;
    transform: translate3d(-90px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes moveTheWave {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -133;
    transform: translate3d(-90px, 0, 0);
  }
}

#wave-stop {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 16 101 16;
  -webkit-animation: none;
          animation: none;
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="play-pause-button">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     width="80px" height="60px"
     viewBox="5 0 80 60">
    <path id="wave" 
        fill="none" 
        stroke="#262626" 
        stroke-width="4"
        stroke-linecap="round">
    </path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are **multiple ways** to achieve that. For example here is a way to use the already implemented "*fa-play*" and "*fa-pause*"-classes:

```css
.fa-pause path {
animation-play-state: running !important;
}
.fa-play path {
animation-play-state: paused !important;
}
```

Then set the starting-class of the surrounding div:

```html
<div id="play-pause-button" class="fa-play">
```

That solves the problem as far as I understood it ;)

Nevertheless **there are plenty of ways to optimize it** - some of the classes and statements are not necessary or not even used. And of course my was of overwriting the „animation-play-state“ is not the cleanest and best, but I think it is a very **short and understandable** solution. Let me know if I got your goal right.

```js
var audio = new Audio("https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3");

$('#play-pause-button').on("click",function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('fa-play'))
   {
     $(this).removeClass('fa-play');
     $(this).addClass('fa-pause');
     audio.play();
   }
  else
   {
     $(this).removeClass('fa-pause');
     $(this).addClass('fa-play');
     audio.pause();
   }
});

audio.onended = function() {
     $("#wave").removeClass('fa-pause');
     $("#wave").addClass('fa-play');
};



const path = document.querySelector('#wave');
const animation = document.querySelector('#moveTheWave');
const m = 0.512286623256592433;

function buildWave(w, h) {

  const a = h / 4;
  const y = h / 2;

  const pathData = [
  'M', w * 0, y + a / 2,
  'c',
  a * m, 0,
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,

  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, a,
  a, a,
  's',
  -(1 - a) * m, -a,
  a, -a].
  join(' ');

  path.setAttribute('d', pathData);
}

buildWave(90, 60);
```

```css
#play-pause-button{
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  height: 110px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 110px;
}

body {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

svg {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wave {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 16 101 16;
  -webkit-animation: infinite;
          animation: moveTheWave 2400ms linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveTheWave {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -133;
    transform: translate3d(-90px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes moveTheWave {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -133;
    transform: translate3d(-90px, 0, 0);
  }
}

.fa-pause path {
animation-play-state: running !important;
}
.fa-play path {
animation-play-state: paused !important;
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="play-pause-button" class="fa-play">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     width="80px" height="60px"
     viewBox="5 0 80 60">
    <path id="wave" 
        fill="none" 
        stroke="#262626" 
        stroke-width="4"
        stroke-linecap="round">
    </path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. this did the trick! I am however struggling to implement the above to my Wordpress site. the SVG is not showing. any ideas?